# string array to array of word

Tags: php, mysql

i have data in my mysql database "Service,House Worker" (without ""), when i access my data from the database i found (Service,House Worker) as it is, when i try to convert with (`var_dump(explode(',',($CheckBoxAnswer)));`) it then its return following :

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "Service,House Worker" }
```

but i want something similar:

```
array(1)
(
    [0] => string(7) "Service"
    [1] => string(13) "House Worker"
)
```

`$CheckBoxAnswer` is contain data i pulled from mysql.
i tried with `var_dump(explode(',',($CheckBoxAnswer)));`
but its not working

Comment: It's not working?

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Too bad. It would help if you would be more precise, you know.

Comment: Can you show more of the code, so we can see what is actually going on with these steps.

Comment: More code and the output of `var_dump($CheckBoxAnswer)` and that `var_dump(explode(',',($CheckBoxAnswer)));`

Comment: $a = str_replace('/','',trim($CheckBoxAnswer)); print_r($CheckBoxAnswer);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var_dump(explode(',',($CheckBoxAnswer[0])));
```

You are tring to explode an array into an another array. You need to specify the string instead.

Comment: `$CheckBoxAnswer` is contain data i pulled from mysql, its not an array $CheckBoxAnswer containing "Service,House Worker" (without double quotation)

Comment: What is the output for this `print_r($CheckBoxAnswer); die;`

Comment: Service,House Worker

Comment: i want something following
`array(1)
(
    [0] => string(7) "Service"
    [1] => string(13) "House Worker"
)`

Comment: it should, but its not

Comment: @ShimulChowdhury I hope when you are doing this `print_r($CheckBoxAnswer); die;`, then you are exactly getting this in your browser: Service,House Worker . RIght?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to trim `$CheckBoxAnswer`

**Because by using var_dump giving string length 26 instead of 20**

Then after use string replace

```
str_replace('/','',$CheckBoxAnswer);
```

After that try to use `var_dump(explode(',',($CheckBoxAnswer)));`